# MD5 check of copied files given their original hash and second directory where they were copied

Tags: linux, bash, unix, hash

I am migrating a list of files to a new place and part of the process is to check if they were correctly copied before deleting original files.

Initially I have a list.txt that has absolute paths to original files and I generate a file that has md5 of original files:

```
    d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /dir1/file
```

Now I need to validate these hashes against the hashes of files in second directory.

My approach is to first change /dir1 to /dir2 in the text file then run:

```
      md5sum -c list.txt
```

My question: Is there a way to run this last command without having to manually change all strings in list.txt to point to dir2:

Comment: Define **manually** ...?  `sed 's/dir1/dir2/' list.txt > newlist.txt; md5sum -c newllist.txt` ...

Comment: This is how I do it currently, but I was thinking if there was a way to do it by directly substituting dir1 to dir2 before calling md5sum --check. Without creating a new file or overwriting the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you (assuming you're sitting in the right place in the filesystem):

```
sed 's/dir1/dir2/' list.txt | md5sum -c
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I assume that (right place in file system) means the directory where list.txt is ?

Comment: Heh. I don't know. **If** `/dir1/` and `/dir2/` are under `/` and that's where `list.txt` also is, then yes.  I'm bound to work on the little data you provide and assumptions.

Comment: I see what you mean. I used dir1 and 2 for simplicity only. My paths start from / and are very long. Thanks for the reply again!